Plotly table object on Colab
In colab, I generate plotly table object as a part of subplot in all graph object is in Ipywidgets.output like:

But I couldn't see first column values.
When I click the plotly bar, reset button, it shows like in :

Code is:
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()
report_data = [[' Total Distance', '29,873,735,731'], [' Average Distance', '382.9']]
output = widgets.Output()
with output:
  fig.add_trace(go.Table(
            header=dict(values=['Summary', ' '], align='left'),
            cells=dict(values=list(zip(*report_data)), align='left'),
        ), row=1, col=1)
  fig.add_trace(go.Table(
            header=dict(values=['Summary', ' '], align='left'),
            cells=dict(values=list(zip(*report_data)), align='left'),
        ), row=1, col=2)
  fig.show(renderer="colab")
display(output)

I tried different browsers, also I gave cell height parameter 35, didn't worked. If I generate table alone, there is not problem. But with output it is not seen normal, if I download as a png, it shows.

I can't reproduce (I'm plotly on 5.18.0), though It seems you are using subplots, and the code that initialize the figure is missing, so I just did fig = go.Figure() and removed the row and col args.

You are right, it is part of subplot which is 2x2 and includes map. If I generate table alone, there is not problem. But on subplot, it needs resize.

Having subplots is (I think) the cause of the issue, please add the full code (ie. fig = make_subplots(...) and the other traces. If it's too complex at least specify which trace types (go.?) are involved for each row/col.

@EricLavault Full working code updated. Problem is "output" related".

You shouldn't need to use widgets.Output() (which is likely the cause of the issue), fig.show() should just work with the proper renderer ("colab"), but you can also set it explicitly.
Regarding the cell height, you can set it in the cells dict.
report_data = [[' Total Distance', '29,873,735,731'], [' Average Distance', '382.9']]

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1,
    cols=2,
    specs=[
        [{"type": "table"}, {"type": "table"}]
    ]
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(values=['Summary', ' '], align='left'),
        cells=dict(values=list(zip(*report_data)), align='left', height=35)
    ),
    row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(values=['Summary', ' '], align='left'),
        cells=dict(values=list(zip(*report_data)), align='left', height=35)
    ),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.show(renderer='colab')

For a 2x2 subplots grid, adapt row, col and specs according to the trace types you want to use at each row/col pair, eg. :
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2,
    cols=2,
    specs=[
        [{"type": "scatter"}, {"type": "table"}],
        [{"type": "scattermapbox"}, {"type": "bar"}]
    ]
)


It is connected to button, therefore I use output widget. "button = widgets.Button(description="Report")
button.on_click(run_report)
display(input_box, button, output)" If I don't use output, buttons disappear after one run.

@kurag Ok, it seems I should have guessed.. Why do you put information one bit after the other, why didn't you provide all the details in your question in the first place, with the full code ? Next time just provide a link to your colab. You can implement custom actions using updatemenus buttons with plotly, @see https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/.

At start I think problem is simple parameter setting, but when you ask I tried and found main reason, sorry for that.
